# Debugger failure on qt-creator caused by python error

Tags: python, macos, debugging, qt-creator

When I start the debugger of qt-creator 4.1.0, on macOs Sierra (10.12.3) it refuses to start, reporting in the debugger console (I report only the relevant part):

```
ERROR: Lldb stderr: File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Resources/Python/lldb/_init_.py", line 98, in <module>
 import six
ImportError: No module named six
```

Seeming related to something wrong in the python installation...

This issue was reported as a bug on qt bug report site, but it was closed without giving a solution.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-17260

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution, for the issue. I report here for others. 
The problem was caused by a second python framework installed on the system (using macport) that was in the path.

The simplest solution is to change the '`run environment`' of qt creator (in the project->run tab), removing from that path the folder containing the second python (in my case I just removed from the qt-creator internal path the /opt/usr/bin folder where the macport binaries are placed)